# Merging additional column info from the main database for some selective records

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, merge, inner-join

I am working with two files that contain millions of records. Just sharing the test data to explain the problem I'm facing. For example, the tx_match.txt has all the records. And txid_time.txt has only a few records that have the timestamps. My desired output is shown below, the idea is to merge the additional column info from the main database. Please note that I am NOT allowed to use pandas library.

tx_match.txt

```
col1  col2  col3      col4
171    9    9    5000000000
183    171    9    4000000000
185    183    9    3000000000
187    185    9    2900000000
192    187    187  100000000
227    185    185  100000000
255    187    9    2800000000
504    367    367  5000000000
504    192    192  100000000
504    255    255  1000000000
533    293    293  5000000000
555    533    533  2500000000
```

txid_time.txt

```
col1      col2
227     2017-02-10
255     2017-01-10
504     2017-02-09
```

My desired output is :

```
227    185     185     100000000   2017-02-10
255    187     9       2800000000  2017-01-10 
504    367     367     5000000000  2017-02-09
504    192     192     100000000   2017-02-09
504    255     255     1000000000  2017-02-09
```

So far I have done this:

```
import csv 
d={}
fin = open("txid_match.txt","r")
for line in fin:
    try:
        line = line.rstrip()
        f = line.split("\t")
        k=f[0]
        v=f[1]
        d[k]=v
    except IndexError:
        continue

fin.close()
#print(d)
fin = open("txid_time.txt","r")
fout = open("txmatch_time.txt",'w')
foutWriter=csv.writer(fout)
for line in fin:
    try:
         line = line.rstrip()
         f = line.split("\t")
         txid=f[0]
         prvtxid=d[txid]    
         foutWriter.writerow([f[0]+"\t"+f[1]+"\t"+prvtxid])
    except IndexError:
         continue
    except KeyError:
         continue
fin.close()    
fout.close()
```

Thanks in advance for the support.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use any library? or just not pandas library?

Comment: @Abhishek , basic python library like csv , I can use. do you have any solution without any library? Looking forward to see it,thanks.

Comment: are you allowed to edit the .txt file? e.g. i would remove all the spaces, and separate the columns with ; and add headers. That would make reading the .txt file a lot easier.

Comment: @J.A.Cado, Sorry for messing up the spacings, as initially, I had deleted some columns. Now , I just added the header and added 4 spacing between the columns. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will work. However, it entails best-case linear space complexity. The following solution improves upon it to achieve best-case constant space complexity. It also makes better use of automated context managers (the `with` statement) as well as the automatic parsing and concatenation features of the `csv` package's `Reader` and `Writer`, respectively. *(note that I left out `IndexError` and `KeyError` handling for clarity; you may need to add them in yourself if required)*

```
import csv

col_delim = '\t'
row_delim = '\n'

with open('txid_time.txt', 'r') as ftime, open('tx_match.txt', 'r') as fmatch, open('txmatch_time.txt', 'w') as fmerge:
    rtime = csv.reader(ftime, delimeter=col_delim, lineterminator=row_delim)
    rmatch = csv.reader(fmatch, delimeter=col_delim, lineterminator=row_delim)
    wmerge = csv.writer(fmerge, delimeter=col_delim, lineterminator=row_delim)

    try:
        time = next(rtime)
        match = next(rmatch)
        continue_ = True
        while continue_:
            while time[0] < match[0]:
                time = next(rtime)
            while time[0] > match[0]:
                match = next(rmatch)
            if time[0] == match[0]:
                key = time[0]
                times = []
                try:
                    while time[0] == key:
                        times.append(time)
                        time = next(rtime)
                except StopIteration:
                    continue_ = False
                matches = []
                try:
                    while match[0] == key:
                        matches.append(match)
                        match = next(rmatch)
                except StopIteration:
                    continue_ = False
                for match in matches:
                   for time in times:
                       merge = match + time[1:2]
                       wmerge.writerow(merge)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```